# Filters in Symfony - how to set default results in list?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

How can i set default result in Symfony Filters in Admin Generator?
I generated backend and i have list all results, for example with News.
I would like default in this view (list) have for example `groups = 'news'`.
I can add for `generator.yml` `table_method` (for list) and for model additional query.
This working ok. Show me only groups news, but if i use filter and select all groups then still i have only groups 'news'. Is possible that default view (immediately after the entry the module news) showing only with `groups = 'news'`, and if i use filter then reset this query?

Maybe instead of additional query can call filter with this option? i can set default value in select list with groups, but this set in javascript, not performed. I must click button Filter.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in `myclassGeneratorConfiguration` class that is in *myproject/apps/backend/modules/mymodule/lib folder* a method to set filter defaults:

```
public function getFilterDefaults()
{    
    return array('groups' => array('text' => 'news'));
}
```